# EVERY other aspect of my PhP code seems to work, but the Echo statements don't appear

Tags: php, echo

The code posts two variables to a MySQL table. The code seems to work perfectly - the only thing that doesn't work is the echo statements. What would cause this?

I'm testing the file locally using MAMP, and the PHP version is up to date. I can't think of anything else that might be causing the problem. The SQL "insert" statements are working perfectly, and every other aspect of the code seems to go off without a hitch.

#### HTML

```
    <body>
    <div>
        First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
        <button id="submitMe" onclick="postData()">Click Here</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

#### JS

```
            function postData(){
            //HTML variable
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
            //Javascript Variable
            var sname = "Second Name";


            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "index.php";
            var params = "fname="+fname+"&sname="+sname;
            http.open("POST", url, true);

            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
                    //alert(http.responseText);
                    alert("Request recieved");
                }
            }
            http.send(params);

        }
```

#### PHP

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)){
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$sname = $_POST['sname'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "tutorials";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed".$conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "insert into tutorials_tbl(firstname, lastname) values('".$fname."', '".$sname."')";

if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo "New Record created successfully";
}else{
    echo "Error: ".$sql."<br/>".$conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: where are you expecting this to output at? in your dev tools/network panel?

Comment: Where do you expect the `echo`-ed strings to show? They are the body of the response but you send the request to the server using AJAX and you don't do anything with the response.

Comment: I was expecting them to show in-browser via html, as they do if I add an Echo statement above the IF statement. Does this make sense?

Comment: The PHP code is exposed to SQL injection. Better use [prepared statements(https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/4265352).

Comment: You can check the response of the AJAX request in the webdeveloper tools console.

Comment: Thanks Axiac for bringing this to my attention! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To echo the PHP statements into your main document, you need to get it via your AJAX script.

**HTML**

Add this where you want the output to be.

```
<span id="output"></span>
```

**JS**

```
if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
    alert("Request recieved");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
```

`this.ResponseText` is getting the output of your PHP document.

Comment: `InnerHTML` is not a property of a DOM [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). It doesn't do what you think it does. The one you are looking for is [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: Thank you, XantiuM and Axiac. This worked...but oddly, the entire html is now re-executing. I get a new "submit" form beneath the old one. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

> What would cause this? (...) I can't think of anything else that might
>   be causing the problem.

It is important to understand the difference between server-side and client-side execution when doing web programming.

Refer to this excellent question (and answers): [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/3258851).

Both HTML and javascript are client-side languages*. They run in the browser, which is the client.

PHP, however, is server-side (it runs on the "server").

In your case, even though you have everything running locally with MAMP, there is still both a client and server. They just happen to be on the same machine. The server is Apache, and it runs PHP code through the `php` executable.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP) (emphasis mine):

> MAMP is an acronym of macOS, the operating system; Apache, the web
>   **server**; MySQL, the database management system; and PHP, Perl, or Python, all programming languages used for web development.

Now, in your example, you have a simple HTML document, with an input field of type "`text`" and a submit button. Normally, both the input field and the submit button would be part of a `<form>` element, but in your code, there is no `<form>`. Instead, you use some javascript to perform the "submit" to the server.

Can you see it? You have the browser run some javascript code, which makes a request to the server. The server processes the request, returns some text but this is never parsed by the javascript who requested.

In your code, I believe you can just uncomment this line:

```
//alert(http.responseText);
```

and it'll show a popup alert with the message from your `echo` statement.

(*) there can be exceptions, none of which are relevant here.

Answer (score -3):

Yes,
The insert query is not perfect.
Pls remove double quotes and use only single quotes.

Comment: What is the difference?